# Is there any package for node.js which provides to connect over ssh to remote machine and execute shell command or run some python scripts?

Tags: node.js

Is there any package for node.js which provides to connect over ssh to remote machine and execute shell command or run some python scripts ?
I done similar with python where I can accept key and process prompt but I need to use node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these would work for your problem:

https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/ssh

But I would suggest trying `node-control` (top of the list) because the project has already rolled many of the features you would be looking to implement.